# AssetBundles for sprites, or download the images from my server?

Tags: unity

I need to host several sprites in my server, and then have Unity download and use them. I have tested two methods:

### AssetBundles

If I pack my sprites into an AssetBundle, the bundle is about 4MB. It works fine.

### Download the images

If I download the image bytes from my server, you can use those bytes to create a Sprite. Curiously, this is much, much smaller than an AssetBundle (just like 1.5MB).

---

Both methods work. It seems pretty obvious that the second one offers an advantage due to reduced memory size. My questions are:

- Why is the second method so much smaller?
- Is there any reason I'd rather use AssetBundles?

Comment: If you use the second option, would you not have to spend the time downloading the assets every time u run the game?

Comment: @Evorlor it depends. You can cache the assets so that they're only downloaded when new assets are available.

Comment: @Evorlor I write my images into the persistent data path. Next time I can just read their bytes.

Comment: I would assume the AssetBundle is doing things like creating minimaps and has some metadata to store since it seems to manage the caching for you. You can use your debugger to drill into the specific instances though and view what data is stored. The documentation doesn't seem to go into adequate detail.